# Renaming an inner join and using it for a subsequent inner join

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, table-rename

So I have three tables.

```
1) business:
-> id           (varchar)  id of business
-> name         (varchar)  name of business

2) review:
-> business_id  (varchar)  id of reviewed business
-> user_id      (varchar)  id of user who reviewed

3) user:
-> id           (varchar)  id of user
-> name         (varchar)  name of user
-> review_count (int)      number of reviews written by the user
```

I want to write a query that extracts the `business.id`s and `business.name`s of those businesses that have been reviewed by those users who have written more than 10 reviews.

I thought about doing an inner join on `user` and `review` on the condition `user.id = review.user_id` where `user.id in (select id from user where review_count > 10)`. This would perform an inner join on the above tables after selecting only those `user.id`'s that belong to users who have written more than 10 reviews. Next I wish to perform an inner join on this new table and the `business` table, on the condition that `business.id = new_table.business_id`, where `new_table` is the table obtained by performing the previous inner join on review and user.

I understand that there could be a problem with my renaming syntax.

I am getting a syntax error : `Error: near "where": syntax error`. I am using sqlite3.

And here is what I have so far.

```
select business.id, business.name
from business inner join  
(                  
review inner join user
on review.user_id = user.id
where user.id in (
select id
from user
where review_count > 10) 
) as R
on R.business_id = business.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below should be the same as what you are trying to do.

```
select business.id, business.name
from business                 
inner join review on review.business_id = business.id
inner join user on user.id = review.user_id 
where user.review_count > 10
```

Comment: Thanks, but review doesn't have a review_count column. so I am not sure if review.review_count > 10 would work. I have fixed my problem statement

Comment: if only we remove the and "review.review_count > 10" and put it at the end of next line, it seems to work.

Comment: I meant that if only we remove the and "review.review_count > 10", change it to " and user.review_count > 10" and append it to the last line, it seems to work

Comment: sure..modified the query to include `review_count` in the `where` clause